# Dimension Search with given number of characters in Endeca

Tags: search, configuration, dimensions, endeca

I have requirement to search an dimension in endeca which start with some word.For example if the dimension is Arena it can be searched with Ar or ar or Are or Aren.

How to achive this ?
What configuration needs to be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is wildcard AR* what you are looking for?

It needs to be enabled on the dimension or property being searched.

Comment: @Wiszh...Thanks a lot for right answer.Now I enabled the wildcard search for that dimension.